# R: Inserting a geom_sf layer on top of another geom_sf layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-sf

I would like to plot a map of France using `geom_sf` and then add a layer to map Germany.

Here's what I did

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(raster)

fr_sf = st_as_sf(getData("GADM",country="FRA",level=1))
de_sf = st_as_sf(getData("GADM",country="DEU",level=0))

ggplot(fr_sf) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray90") + 
  geom_sf(de_sf, fill = "gray90")
```

but I get an error `` mapping` must be created by `aes() ``

I tried with `geom_sf(de_sf, fill = "gray90")[[1]]`, but I got the same error.

Could some help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data =`  like

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#  Loading required package: sp

fr_sf <- st_as_sf(getData("GADM", country = "FRA", level = 1))
de_sf <- st_as_sf(getData("GADM", country = "DEU", level = 0))

ggplot(data = fr_sf) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray90") +
  geom_sf(data = de_sf, fill = "gray90")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, why don't I need `data = ` for `fr_sf` but I need that for `de_sf`?

Comment: Because the first argument of  `geom_sf()` function is `mapping=aes()`; `data` (default NULL) is the second one, so without `mapping` you have to provide `data = ` argument. Please check the help to `geom_sf()` function.

Comment: You should - technically - be able to get away with using `geom_sf(, de_sf, fill = "gray90")` ; note the comma after opening bracket to force the dw_sf to the required second position. But it is not quite the best practice and referencing the data by name (instead of position) has a much better code smell